# Mac graphical glitch, UI replaced with gradients?

Tags: macos, mac, graphics, bug

I'm currently running on a Mac Mini (2014 Model) and recently although rare I have been experiencing some strange graphical glitches, it seems to replace parts of my UI and whenever I open an application with a green and red gradient. I'm not sure if this is driver related or memory perhaps? - Regardless any help or info as to what is causing this would help!

**Edit:**
The resolution is 1440p (Thunderbolt -> DisplayPort Adapter) and is running on OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

[image: Glitch Demo]

Comment: Does it appear on screenshots?

Comment: Yes the above example is a screenshot

Comment: Are those boxes where the application or window would be, always in the same place, apparently random, or something else?

Comment: They appear where the Window should be but the UI bug can affect whole widnows, parts of windows and parts of the top menu bar ...